# Ember CLI Install Addon

Tags: ember-cli

can somebody tell me the difference between using ember install  and npm install ... the docs are very slim in describing the exact function of ember install.

Does ember install, actually call npm install?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, yes, `ember install <addon-name>` does execute `npm install --save-dev <addon-name>`.

However, it'll also  perform any necessary additional setup required by the "blueprint" or add-on hooks (adding bower dependencies, editing a .jshintrc file, or many other tasks).  This might not be applicable to some add-ons, but it is a good idea to use `ember install` over `npm install` for add-ons.

Normal `npm` packages will be installed by using `ember install`, but they won't contain a blueprint - so basically it'd be the same as using `npm install` in that case.

From the docs:

```
ember install <addon-name> - Installs the given addon to your project and saves it to the package.json.  It will run the addon’s defaultBlueprint if it provides one.
```

You can read more about blueprints [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#blueprints).

Hope this helps.  I'm not sure this is thoroughly documented anywhere, this is just my understanding of the process from my usage.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to hear, thanks for clearing that up!